# W/audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL flooding logcat?

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, logcat

I made a mediaplayer app with a media service which controls my mediaplayer object.

Everything works fine but my logcat gets flooded with this message every second.

What does this message mean?

**Logcat (info)**

```
W/audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 
7310473 , only wrote 7310160
W/audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 
7326138 , only wrote 7326000
W/audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 
7326108 , only wrote 7326000   
W/audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 
7328176 , only wrote 7326720
W/audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 
7330512 , only wrote 7330320
W/audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 7333401 , only wrote 7333200
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some research i found some useful link to this issue.

Actually this is the warning given by Hardware Abstraction Layer(Hal).

What is Hal? you can find about it here :

- https://www.coursera.org/lecture/androidapps-2/android-hardware-abstraction-layer-hal-noH7V
- https://www.e-consystems.com/blog/system-on-module-SOM/android-hal-and-device-driver-architecture/

HAL works like the connection b/w software and hardware layer.

After a bit more searching I found the file where this log is coded..

https://android.googlesource.com/device/generic/goldfish/+/master/audio/audio_hw.c#512

Where we can see that `some_position > some_frames_written` which may be causing this warning.

Also, this warning generally comes in [Generic Devices](https://www.indiastudychannel.com/experts/33895-What-generic-Android-device-waht-pros-cons-it.aspx) like emulator or pure android devices. Did you tried the app on real device or by changing device? I think this issue is not related to your application but to your device.

PS : I have just searched these things and don't have much knowledge about them. May be i am wrong about the issue.

Comment: No you're absolutely right, it only shows the message on an emulator and not on a real device. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Welcome, actually I too searched about this issue but no one answered to those question, so researched about it deeper.